# Use Keycloak Authorization Services with Spring Boot (resource server)

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

**How do I use Keycloak Authorization Services with Spring Boot resource server?**

I have a client in keycloak set to bearer-only, and can protect resource paths using information from their documentation.

BUT not when "Authorization Enabled" set to true for my bearer-only client and I have setup resources, policies, permissions.

From the Keycloak documentation https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/authorization_services/topics/enforcer/keycloak-enforcement-filter.html
"You can enforce authorization decisions for your applications if you are using Keycloak OIDC adapters.
When you enable policy enforcement for your Keycloak application, the corresponding adapter intercepts all requests to your application and enforces the authorization decisions obtained from the server."

In application.properties I set:
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.enforcement-mode=enforcing

and get error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.keycloak.authorization.client.ClientAuthenticator
```

I added dependency

```
<dependency> <!-- https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-3246 -->
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-authz-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

but this gives errors as below when trying to access a resource

```
Client 'resourceserver-springboot' doesn't have secret available
org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpResponseException: Unexpected response from server: 400 / Bad Request
```

Comment: Why do you add the keycloak-test-helper dependenc ? This has nothing to do with authz . Anyway, you can take a look at  https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/master/app-authz-springboot

Comment: Sorry mistake in my question not keycloak-test-helper, rather keycloak-authz-client I will updated question.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, it looks like that demo is for Keycloak version 3.2.0.CR1-SNAPSHOT. I am using version 3.1.0.Final.  Would I be able to get this running on 3.1.0.Final or is there a need to wait for changes in new release ?

Comment: Yes it should work with 3.1.Final just make to have `keycloak-authz-client` dependency in your pom.xml.

Comment: i am bit late here.. is this problem solved if not can you share pom.xml and application.properties file. even i was getting this my mistake was doing boot and spring-security config both.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to pass the secret in your config : 
`keycloak.credentials.secret=my_secret`

Comment: I had yes, however even with adding it in I still get error along the lines of 'org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpResponseException: Unexpected response from server: 400 / Bad Request]' I do know API works as tested that before including Keycloak Authorisation Services. Seem wrong to be using keycloak-authz-client  for a pure resource server. Am busy working through the quickstart you sent me. At first glance it seems that is an example of a client web app, not a resource server.

Comment: It is not wrong for a Resource Server to use kc-authz-client. Reason being the RS should be able to access some APIs in order to manage resources.
Also, when using UMA, there is also an API for obtaining permission tickets.
The quickstart is basically both a client and RS.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I've that quickstart working for 3.1.0.Final. 
But cannot protect a JSON response I added to ApplicationController:
    '@RequestMapping(value = "/protected/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, String> hello() {
        return Collections.singletonMap("message", "hello");
    }'
and removed the freemarker depencency from pom.xml. 
I have also added a resource (/protected/hello/*) in keycloak with premissions & policy setup as /protected/premium/*
URL http://localhost:8081/protected/hello/ redirects to log into Keycloak, as jdoe/jdoe I get a 404 error

Comment: Oh no, the 404 error is my mistake! ApplicationController is a Controller where as I need a RestController for JSON response.

Comment: Ok I now am about to protect a JSON end point with Auth Services, Questions: 1) why do I still need the keycloak.securityConstraints[0] settings. Does this mean all my users have to have role of user? My understanding is that all auth config can now be done within Keycloak. Am I misunderstanding this? 2) I cannot set Access Type to bearer-only with keycloak.bearer-only=true, as this causes a Unexpected response from server: 400 / Bad Request from : seems to use Auth Services Access Type must be confidential please help my understand that. As I want to protect a pure RS. Thanks again in advance

Answer (score 0):

- Add keycloak.json to your resources,(Usually keycloak adapter looks
  for a keycloak.json for configs)

OR

- Add config into your    application.properties file.
  Also create a bean to resolve your application.properties for the
  keycloak adapter

  @Bean
  open fun keycloakConfigResolver(): KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver {
  return KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver()
  }